# How to have LinearLayout's weights in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout and I would like to have the same behavior as `weightSum` and `weight` in a `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#a4c639"
            android:thelayout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Main information"
        />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#a4c639"
            android:thelayout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"

            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linear_layout_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/linear_layout_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear_layout_1"
    >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="foo"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bar"
            android:thelayout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/linear_layout_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linear_layout_2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/linear_layout_2"
            android:background="#a4c639"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it show:
[image]

I would like all the 3 widgets to occupy 1/3 of the space each. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use weights with `ConstraintLayout`, you must make sure that all views you want weighted form a *chain*. In this case, we'll be dealing with a *horizontal chain*, which means that the start + end (or left + right) of every view must be constrained to its neighbors or the parent.

For example:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/first"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/second"
    .../>

<View
    android:id="@+id/second"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/third"
    .../>

<View
    android:id="@+id/third"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/second"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    .../>
```

If you want the views to be spread evenly, then you should use `MATCH_CONSTRAINTS` (`0dp`) for the width of each view:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    .../>

<View
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    .../>

<View
    android:id="@+id/third"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    .../>
```

If you want to change how the views are weighted, you must specify the weight on each view (in addition to setting the widths to `0dp`). Here, the middle view will be twice as large as the two side views:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/first"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    .../>

<View
    android:id="@+id/second"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
    .../>

<View
    android:id="@+id/third"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    .../>
```

Comment: For a view that has not been declared yet, we don't need to use `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second"` like with `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Modern versions of AAPT will parse the layout and generate the ids for each view "before" trying to parse the constraints, so you can use `@id/second` on the first view, even though `@+id/second` appears later in the file.

Comment: Though tbh it's really not problematic to use the `@+id` syntax everywhere. You just get slightly better help from lint if you use the `@id` syntax.

Comment: Awesome! If in the chain I had a view that acted as a divider i.e. width 2dp that would work because for only for the views with 0dp width the constraints will work right?